# sqlserver: Get Sum from three table

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the result from three table

1. limit
2. transfer_hold
3. transfer_done

**limit** table details are

```
transfer_amount | amount

SELF | 2000

OTHER| 5000
```

--
**transfer_hold** table details are

```
transfer_type | amount1 | date

SELF | 1.0|2020-03-18

SELF | 3.0|2020-03-18

SELF | 6.0|2020-03-18

OTHER| 2.0|2020-03-18

SELF | 1.0|2020-03-19

OTHER| 2.0|2020-03-19
```

--
**transfer_done** table details are

```
transfer_type | amount2 | date

SELF | 10.0|2020-03-18

SELF | 30.0|2020-03-18

SELF | 60.0|2020-03-18

OTHER| 20.0|2020-03-18

SELF | 10.0|2020-03-19

OTHER| 20.0|2020-03-19
```

that means first table is for max limit, second table is for hold amount for given date and 3rd table is for successful transfer for given date.
Now I want result in below format

transfer_type|amount1+amount2|max_limit|date

```
SELF| 110.0 | 2000|2020-03-18

OTHER| 28.0 | 5000| 2020-03-18

SELF| 11.0 | 2000|2020-03-19

OTHER| 22.0 | 5000| 2020-03-19
```

any suggestion/solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just union your 2 tables together as they have the exact same structure, and then just aggregate/sum them as needed with a join to the first table.

```
WITH Unioned AS
(
    SELECT transfer_type, amount1 as amt, date FROM transfer_hold
    UNION ALL
    SELECT transfer_type, amount2 as amt, date FROM transfer_done    
),
Grouped AS
(
    SELECT transfer_type, SUM(amt) as total_amt, date
    FROM Unioned
    GROUP BY transfer_type,date
)
SELECT
    g.transfer_type,
    g.total_amt
    m.amount as max_limit,
    g.date
FROM Grouped g
INNER JOIN limit m ON g.transfer_type = m.transfer_amount
```

This can be shortened, but thats probably the easiest way to visualise what its doing